# Attempting to loop through list of dataframes and perform operation on one column in each dataframe

Tags: r

I'm attempting to loop through a list of dataframes that I have and for the same column in each dataframe, sum up that column then divide it by the number of rows in that dataframe and print it out. Not add a row/column to a new dataframe, I just want it to print the result out for each one. I also want it to print out the number of rows in each dataframe separately.

I created this list of dataframes by using this `for` loop:

```
Coverages <- list('Cover 0', 'Cover 1', 'Cover 2', 'Cover 3')

DoublePostsLeftDFs <- c()

for (x in Coverages) {
    assign(paste("DoublePostsLeft", str_replace_all(x, " ", ""), sep=""), DoublePostsLeft %>% filter(CoverageScheme == x))
    name <- paste("DoublePostsLeft", str_replace_all(x, " ", ""), sep="")
    DoublePostsLeftDFs <- append(DoublePostsLeftDFs, name)
```

This successfully creates all the dataframes I need, but I didn't know a better way to make a list of what they were all named which is where I suspect my problem is coming from. Here is what I've attempted to do so far:

```
for (x in DoublePostsLeftDFs) {
    row_number <- nrow(x)
    average <- sum(x$desired_column)/nrow(x)

    print(row_number)
    print(average)
}
```

When I use that I the error: `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

So then I tried this:

```
for (x in DoublePostsLeftDFs) {
    new <- as.data.frame(x)
    row_number <- nrow(new)
    average <- sum(new$desired_column)/nrow(new)

    print(row_number)
    print(average)
}
```

And all it did was print out:

```
[1] 1
[1] 0
```

for each dataframe in the list. I suspect it has something to do with how I created the list of the dataframes? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are your dataframes stored from which you are creating list of dataframes? What is `Coverages` ?

Comment: This part: `for (x in DoublePostsLeftDFs) {...sum(x$desired_column)/nrow(x)` It looks like the items you're iterating over are atomic vectors like `letters` or `1:3`, not data frames.

Comment: @RonakShah sorry that was supposed to be ```list``` instead of ```c()```. @svenhalvorson should I convert them to a dataframe before the loop then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a need to create list of dataframes here. Is this what you want?

```
library(dplyr)

result <- DoublePostsLeft %>%
  group_by(CoverageScheme) %>%
  summarise(nrow = n(), 
            average = mean(desired_column, na.rm = TRUE))

result
```